# Bone moves completely instead of rotating on axis

Tags: rigging, bones

[image]I made this armature watching a newbie video. The upper arm bone was created on its own and not extruded out of the shoulder bone. So now it has no rotation axis like the other bones. Instead of rotating on an axis in pose mode, it just moves the entire bone. I've parented it to the shoulder. Still it does not have an axis at all. This is my first character. So frustrating. Please help. Thank you.enter image description here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In edit mode enable the connected check box as depicted below.

[image]